# How to get value from submitted button in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

Don't know a better title but here is what im trying to do.

I have the following form where which will display a list of books and after every book entry there is a remove button. The list can be any length. In order to get the book id I have set `name="remove[${cartItem.bookId}]"` but how do I get this value in a servlet? `request.getParameter("remove")` and `request.getParameterValues("remove")` returns null everytime.

```
  <form method="post" action="removeBookFromCart">
<c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${sessionScope.cart.cartItems}">
        <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${cartItem.title}" /></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="remove[${cartItem.bookId}]" value="Remove"/></td>
        </tr>  
    </c:forEach>
    </form>
```

Comment: The syntax which you've there works for PHP only. PHP has the extra feature that it automatically translates request parameter names ending with `[]` into an array on `$_REQUEST`. This feature is not part of HTTP nor HTML, so you shouldn't expect to see the same in all other web based languages/APIs. PHP covers with this the lack of support for something like as `getParameterValues()` which conforms HTTP/HTML specs of multiple input elements with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use hidden parameters:

```
<input type="hidden" name="remove" value="${cartItem.bookId}"/>
```

Let the submit button be just this way:

```
<input type="submit" value="Remove"/>
```

EDIT:
Yes, you have to create a form element for each book:

```
<c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${sessionScope.cart.cartItems}">        
        <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${cartItem.title}" /></td>
          <td>
            <form method="post" action="removeBookFromCart">
             <input type="submit" value="Remove"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="remove" value="${cartItem.bookId}"/>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>      
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work if there's only one entry though? I will have multiple entries with corresponding remove buttons.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions:

1. Use `<button name="bookToRemove" value="${cartItem.bookId}" type="submit">Remove</button>`. This, however, doesn't work as specified in IE6 and IE7 (at least).
2. Iterate through the parameters, find the one which starts with `remove[`, and extract the ID after that. You could use a simpler name, such as `remove_${cartItem.bookId}`
3. Create one form per cart item, instead of a global form, and use a hidden field to contain the book to remove.

The third way is probably the easiest one.

You could also use some JavaScript to initialize the value of a hidden field when a button is clicked, but this is not easier than the methods above, and requires JavaScript.